# simplest way to make a non-responsive joomla website to a responsive one

Tags: html, css, joomla, responsive-design

I have a website in joomla and now i want to convert it into responsive design so that it runs fine on mobiles and tablets as well. As far as i have searched on net, but couldn't find something concrete. I don't have much time so was searching for a simple, easy and fast solution for converting my non-responsive website to a responsive one.
Please help me out.

Comment: Creating a responsive website from a non-responsive one is not something that can be done quickly. Unless there's a responsive Joomla layout already built, you're in for a lot of time editing code.

Comment: Actually i have to finish this site and have to start my travel during which i wont be able to work on it, that's why i was looking for a simpler option. Is there anyway by which we can handle it on mobiles only and not convert it into full responsive thing??

Comment: In your situation, I'd follow @cppl's advice and use a mobile solution, for now, and revisit the responsive issue later. Creating a good responsive site cannot be done quickly, and needs to be approached properly... mobile first. One issue that is commonly overlooked with responsive design is that responsive does not mean mobile-friendly. Take a quick look at http://timothybrand.com/website-design/responsive-design-mobile-friendly/for an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably to use one of the Joomla extensions listed in the [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) (JED), have a look at the [Mobile Display](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/mobile/mobile-display) section and products like [JTouch](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/mobile/mobile-display/19123) and the popular [Mobile](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/mobile/mobile-display/11722).

Simply dropping "[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)" in won't make your site responsive, apart from the conversions mentioned by [@Dasun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1263783/dasun) in many cases your content will have to be updated as well (especially images).

When you've got more time and want to make you site fully responsive there are several options available in the JED for "Responsive" modules, galleries etc. Simply [search the JED for "Responsive"](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=Responsive).

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is

- Convert the Joomla template to be a responsive one
- Convert the Joomla component views to be responsive
- Convert the Joomla modules views to be responsive

I would recommend [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Actually i have to finish this site and have to start my travel during which i wont be able to work on it, that's why i was looking for a simpler option so that i can finish it off in like 2 days as i dont have much time left. Is there anyway by which we can handle it on mobiles only and not convert it into full responsive thing??

Comment: see im new to this responsive thing...will installing and uploading these bootstrap files will do the trick???